# What does it mean when a Sigma has two variables at the bottom

Tags: summation, notation

In a [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1531050) I'm reading there is a sigma notation that I'm not understanding. They have two variables at the bottom of the sigma.

### From the paper:

A finite set of requirements Req = {r<sub>1</sub>,...,r<sub>n</sub>} and D is a distribution,
satisfying the following normalization property:
$$
\sum\limits_{r_i,r_j} D(r_i,r_j) = 1
$$

So does that mean that we are going to sum all of the combinations of r<sub>i</sub> and r<sub>j</sub> where i != j?  So if n=5 we would have (5 choose 2) = 10 combinations to sum.  Is that right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You have $$\sum\limits_{r_i,r_j} D(r_i,r_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n D(r_i,r_j)$$

Which means that the sum is over all combinations $(i,j) \in \{1, \dots ,n\}^2$. Not only the ones for which $i \neq j$. The notation for this last case would be $$\sum_{i \neq j} D(r_i,r_j).$$

Comment: So there is no difference between putting r_i,r_j and i,j under the sigma right?

Comment: No, I don't think so. However to avoid ambiguity, it is better to explicitely mention the set of which the sum is performed.